# Aclaracion sobre include, require PhP

Tags: php, html, poo

Llevo un rato buscando por el foro y no encontre la respuesta que busco. Imaginar que desde mi fichero index, llamo a un fichero php que esta en ./nivel1/mifichero.php suponiendo que nivel1 es una subcarpeta. Si a su vez desntro de "mifichero.php" hago otra llamada mediante include, a otro fichero, ¿que ruta es la que se toma en cuenta? la que parte desde el index.php o la que parte desde "mifichero.php.

Comment: seria la que parte de tu mifichero.php desde ahi  estaras realizando cualquier llamada a algun directorio anterior o posterior.

Comment: El punto de partida de las rutas para la aplicación es el punto de partida inicial, es decir todas las rutas van a ser relativas al directorio en que se encuentre `index.php` revisa la doc de las superglobales __FILE__ y __DIR__: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Pues sigue sin quedarme muy claro, no se si me podriais hacer un ejemplo sencillo. Me he leido el enlace y me he quedado como estaba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a tratar de explicarlo de la forma mas gráfica que pueda para que se entienda el caso:

Tengo este directorio con sus respectivas carpetas y archivos:

```
/dirBase
   |----index.php
   |----/dir1
          |-----uno.php
          |-----/dir2
                  |------dos.php
```

Teniendo en cuenta estas rutas:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
        include("dir1/dir2/dos.php");
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

dir1/uno.php:

```
<h1 style="background-color:#ccc; padding:10px;">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor.
</h1>
```

dir1/dir2/dos.php:

```
<div style="background-color: #45aa3a;  padding:10px;">
    <?php
        include("dir1/uno.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

Si analizamos el index, desde aqui se hace una llamada a *dir1/dir2/dos.php*

En el fichero *dos.php* se hace una llamada a un fichero de un directorio superior, pero no lo llama con la ruta *../uno.php*, al contrario, lo llama con *dir1/uno.php*, como si este archivo estuviera en la misma ruta que el *index.php*.

Y de hecho se trata de eso...

Citando la documentación oficial de PHP:

> Cuando se incluye un archivo, el código que contiene hereda el ámbito de las variables
>   en el cual ocurre la inclusión.

Esto aplica también para las rutas:

> ..., si un nombre de archivo comienza con ../, el interprete buscará en el
>   directorio padre para encontrar el archivo solicitado.

Como el archivo *dos.php* es incluido dentro del index, las rutas relativas que maneje este archivo los tomará en cuenta como si su ubicación estuviera al mismo nivel.

---

Por si las dudas te dejo el enlace:

[include()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)

Comment: Esta muy bien explicado te lo agradezco. Pero se me presenta otra duda, si por ejemplo la llamada inicial, en vez de hacerla desde el index.php, la hago por ejemplo desde dir1/paginas/inicio.php . Las rutas ya no me funcionan, abria una solucion para que funcionen sea quien sea el que inicia la llamada?

Comment: Podrías usar la variable *$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']* concatenándolo antes de las rutas para poder controlar de una mejor forma los directorios... Te dejo este enlace para un mejor entendimiento:    https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php